# Can Gradle use an already compiled Android APK as a dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm not too familiar with the Android build process, so I'm sorry if this comes off as a really stupid question.

Anyway, I'm writing testing code utilizing ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and Robotium for an Android application by the company I work for.

The company is rather large, so the transition to Gradle is going very slow. I would like to use Gradle for my testing project for ease and future maintainability, but right now the application I'm testing is built using a combination of ANT scripts and manual intervention with all dependencies checked in as jars in the repository. I'm not at all involved in that process, but I know it's pretty hacked together.

From what I understand, Gradle cannot simply depend on and trigger the building of another existing Android project unless that project also utilizes Gradle. So unless I want to really get my hands dirty with the build process of our application (we have people who are literally hired to only deal with that), I'm out of luck.

What I do have access to, however, are debug builds of our application.

So my question is, is there some way that I can have Gradle use the compiled debug APK as a local file dependency, or can APKs not work like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APKs don't work like that; you can't depend on them, for a variety of reasons. The most important reason is that the code and resources are processed and compressed and much of the original information needed to build them is lost at that point.

You'll have a tough time getting it to work properly. If things that you depend on are pure Java libraries, then if you could get them in JAR format you could depend on them from a Gradle project pretty easily. But if they're Android projects containing resources and manifest entries and such, then there isn't a compiled file format you could obtain those libraries in that would be compatible with Gradle. Gradle supports the AAR format for Android libraries, but that format is generated by Gradle and nothing else.